# (lwjgl) Light seems to be rotating with camera?

Tags: java, lwjgl

So, I have a simple project. Just a simple model in the center, and you can fly around it, and the light follows you. I just have one little problem... The light seems to rotate with the camera. If you don't look directly at the object, it won't light up. Here is my rendering code:

```
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        //RENDER MODE
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_POLYGON);
        int delta = getDelta();

        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glRotatef(rotation.x, 1, 0, 0);
        glRotatef(rotation.y, 0, 1, 0);
        glRotatef(rotation.z, 0, 0, 1);
        glTranslatef(position.x, position.y, position.z);
        int objectDisplayList = glGenLists(1);
        glNewList(objectDisplayList, GL_COMPILE);
        {
            //Drawing Model
            glColor3f(0.54f,0.27f,0.17f);
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            for(Face face : m.faces){
                Vector3f n1 = m.normals.get((int) face.normal.x - 1);
                glNormal3f(n1.x, n1.y, n1.z);
                Vector3f v1 = m.vertices.get((int) face.vertex.x - 1);
                glVertex3f(v1.x, v1.y, v1.z);
                Vector3f n2 = m.normals.get((int) face.normal.y - 1);
                glNormal3f(n2.x, n2.y, n2.z);
                Vector3f v2 = m.vertices.get((int) face.vertex.y - 1);
                glVertex3f(v2.x, v2.y, v2.z);
                Vector3f n3 = m.normals.get((int) face.normal.z - 1);
                glNormal3f(n3.x, n3.y, n3.z);
                Vector3f v3 = m.vertices.get((int) face.vertex.z - 1);
                glVertex3f(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z);
            }
            glEnd();
        }
        glEndList();
        glCallList(objectDisplayList);
        glRotatef(rotation.x, -1, 0, 0);
        glRotatef(rotation.y, 0, -1, 0);
        glRotatef(rotation.z, 0, 0, -1);
        glTranslatef(-position.x, -position.y, -position.z);
        lightPosition = new float[]{position.x, position.y, position.z, 1};
        glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, asFloatBuffer(lightPosition));
```

Also, the asFloatBuffer method is:

```
private static FloatBuffer asFloatBuffer(float[] values) {
    FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(values.length);
    buffer.put(values);
    buffer.flip();
    return buffer;
}
```

And I know for sure that the light is being put in the right place, because I had it outputting the positions of both the player and the light in the console, and they were always the same. What's happening?

EDIT: Even if the light doesn't move, it still does that.

EDIT: edited the code, this code that I just updated doesn't make the light rotate with the camera, but the light doesn't move, and if I put translatefs around the light code it makes it rotate again :/

Answer (score 0):

If the light is rotating with your camera, then `glRotate` is the problem cause. Probably you're calling it in the wrong place, and as I don't know your full code, I can't help you much, but try to do something like:

```
doYourRotation()
draw()
undoYourRotation()
drawLight()
```

To undo the rotation, pass the rotation angle as `negative`, like:

```
doYourRotation -> glRotate(1.0D...)
undoYourRotation -> glRotate(-1.0D...)
```

Comment: I tried that, and it _kinda_ worked. I edited my original post with new code. Now when I use the new code, the light doesn't move with the player, put it doesn't rotate anymore which is good. I've also tried putting push and pop matrix around the light translation and translatef and the negative translatef.